# Mediawiki-Docker cannot connect the database

Tags: docker, ubuntu, mediawiki

I am setting the MediaWiki-Docker up on my server (os: Ubuntu 20.04)  according to the [official documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki-Docker/zh). I tried to visit my website and catch an error when I finish all the steps.

The error is:

```
Sorry! This site is experiencing technical difficulties.
Try waiting a few minutes and reloading.

(Cannot access the database: No database connection (unknown))

Backtrace:

#0 /var/www/html/w/includes/libs/rdbms/loadbalancer/LoadBalancer.php(956): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LoadBalancer->reportConnectionError()
#1 /var/www/html/w/includes/libs/rdbms/loadbalancer/LoadBalancer.php(928): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LoadBalancer->getServerConnection(0, 'my_wiki', 0)
#2 /var/www/html/w/includes/libs/rdbms/loadbalancer/LoadBalancer.php(1086): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LoadBalancer->getConnection(-1, Array, 'my_wiki', 0)
#3 /var/www/html/w/includes/GlobalFunctions.php(2190): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LoadBalancer->getMaintenanceConnectionRef(-1, Array, 'my_wiki')
#4 /var/www/html/w/includes/user/User.php(524): wfGetDB(-1)
#5 /var/www/html/w/includes/libs/objectcache/wancache/WANObjectCache.php(1690): User->{closure}(false, 3600, Array, NULL, Array)
#6 /var/www/html/w/includes/libs/objectcache/wancache/WANObjectCache.php(1518): WANObjectCache->fetchOrRegenerate('global:user:id:...', 3600, Object(Closure), Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/w/includes/user/User.php(557): WANObjectCache->getWithSetCallback('global:user:id:...', 3600, Object(Closure), Array)
#8 /var/www/html/w/includes/user/User.php(468): User->loadFromCache()
#9 /var/www/html/w/includes/user/User.php(401): User->loadFromId(0)
#10 /var/www/html/w/includes/session/UserInfo.php(92): User->load()
#11 /var/www/html/w/includes/session/CookieSessionProvider.php(127): MediaWiki\Session\UserInfo::newFromId('1')
#12 /var/www/html/w/includes/session/SessionManager.php(531): MediaWiki\Session\CookieSessionProvider->provideSessionInfo(Object(WebRequest))
#13 /var/www/html/w/includes/session/SessionManager.php(253): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager->getSessionInfoForRequest(Object(WebRequest))
#14 /var/www/html/w/includes/WebRequest.php(842): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager->getSessionForRequest(Object(WebRequest))
#15 /var/www/html/w/includes/session/SessionManager.php(172): WebRequest->getSession()
#16 /var/www/html/w/includes/Setup.php(877): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager::getGlobalSession()
#17 /var/www/html/w/includes/WebStart.php(93): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#18 /var/www/html/w/index.php(44): require('/var/www/html/w...')
#19 {main}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

The error may be related to the database, but I tried the same on my computer and it worked successfully.

I tried to search the error everywhere and there are some question like this but they did not have the correct answer.

Help me, a noob.